# How to validate number ranges of the form ]0,100000]

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need to validate numbers where the validation rule looks like this (for example):

```
]0,1000[
```

meaning that the numbers are only valid in the range >0 and <=1000

Also there is validation rule like:

```
[*,*]
```

which means: every number is allowed (don't ask me about the max and min).

Is there an existing library to validate this with generic rules like that? Do you have example code I could use?

Thanks
Hannes

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_number would this help you? Look at the function `myFunction()` validation

Comment: no, what I am trying to achieve is a generic lib which can validate numbers in javascript using the validation rules described above

Comment: Are your numbers entered on a form or passed to a function?

Comment: does not matter, lets say as a function

Comment: Personally i would use `isNan()`. Stands for “is Not a Number”, if variable is not a number, it return true, else return false. If you need an example, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lib for this, its possible with simple if-statements. I while ago I build a solution with php, but you can easily transfer it to javascript.

```
$rule = ['*', 200];
$n = 65;

if($rule[0] == '*' && $n <= $rule[1]){
  echo 'Valid';
} elseif($rule[1] == '*' && $n >= $rule[0]){
  echo 'Valid';
} elseif($rule[0] == '*' && $rule[1] == '*'){
  echo 'Valid';
} elseif($n <= $rule[1] && $n >= $rule[0]){
  echo 'Valid';
} else {
  echo 'Invalid';
}
```

Comment: don‘t forget that you also have [, ]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you'll find a library for this as it is too simple.

Personally i would just bundle a bunch of validation functions in a validator object and test against those:

```js
var Validator = /** @class */ (function() {
  function Validator(name, tests) {
    if (tests === void 0) {
      tests = [];
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.tests = tests;
  }
  Validator.prototype.test = function(n) {
    var m = parseFloat(n.toString());
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tests.length; i++) {
      var test = this.tests[i];
      if (!test(m)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
  return Validator;
}());
//TEST
var validator = new Validator("between0And1000", [
  function(n) {
    return n >= 0;
  },
  function(n) {
    return n <= 1000;
  },
]);
console.log(validator.test(-1), validator.test(0), validator.test(1), validator.test(10), validator.test(999), validator.test(1000), validator.test(1001));
```

If you are serious about providing "patterns" then you should look into regular expressions